# 63 is not equal to 2^(log(63)/log(2)) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, precision, logarithm

Because of the floating point error 2^(log(63)/log(2)) isn't equal to 63. Check the results below:

```
format long;
>> 2^(log(63)/log(2))

ans =

  63.000000000000014
```

And unfortunatelly i can't use vpa on a logarithm according to the Matlab documents:

> Unlike exact symbolic values, double-precision values inherently
>   contain round-off errors. **When you call vpa on a double-precision
>   input, vpa cannot restore the lost precision**, even though it returns
>   more digits than the double-precision value. However, vpa can
>   recognize and restore the precision of expressions of the form p/q,
>   pπ/q, (p/q)1/2, 2q, and 10q, where p and q are modest-sized integers.

So how can i solve this issue ? I have very big numbers like 2^200 and i get very big errors.

Edit: I'm not asking why it is happening. I'm asking how to make this work as 100% accurate so this isn't a duplicate.

**The best solution so far:**

Unfortunatelly the solution that is suggested by @Sardar_Usama isn't always working as intended. Check the results below:

```
>> sym(2^(log(2251799813685247)/log(2)))

ans =

2251799813685259
```

On the other hand

```
>> 2^(log(vpa(2251799813685247))/log(vpa(2)))

ans =

2.2517998136852470000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0*10^0*10^15
```

is much much more closer to 2251799813685247 = 2^51. It's error is around ~9.491*10^-494 which makes this the best solution so far but there is still some error.

Comment: What's the specific issue? Is it how to avoid floating point inaccuracy in general? Or is it how to evaluate 2^(log(k) / log(2)) without inaccuracy?

Comment: What's wrong with it not being exactly 63? It's only a `2*eps(63)` difference. In general, numerical calculations shouldn't rely on exact values.

Comment: @horcler It gets significantly higher when you work with big numbers.

Comment: @Paul Hankin without inaccuracy

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot use `round` or `vpa`, there is a slower way of dealing this, if you have *Symbolic Math Toolbox*, by [creating symbolic numbers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html) . i.e.

```
a = sym(2^(log(63)/log(2)))
```

This will give you `sym` class `63` which you can later convert to [**`double`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) using:

```
double(a)
```

---

This is what you'll get:

```
>> format long
>> a = sym(2^(log(63)/log(2)))

a =

63

>> double(a)

ans =

    63
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this isn't always working as intended. Check this out `sym(2^(log(2251799813685247)/log(2)))` = `2251799813685259`. (btw 2251799813685247 is 2^51) On the other hand, `2^(log(vpa(2251799813685247))/log(vpa(2)))` is much much more closer to `2251799813685247`. It's error is around `~2.252*10^-192` which is not causing any trouble for my calculations but there is still some error.

Comment: @Kitiara There are only two options: *symbolic  arithmetic* and *numeric arithmetic* (which includes *variable precision* and *double precision*). There *is* no other option. Getting 100% accuracy is not always possible. Read this article: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/recognize-and-avoid-roundoff-errors.html